# How Can I Use a Variable From One Function in Another

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code where there are a bunch of if statements in each function. I want to be able to use a variable from a previous function and then add that variable into another function.

Here is an example:

```
def main():
    name = input('What is your name?')
    age = int(input('What is your age?'))

    number = int(input('What is your favourite number?'))

    if number > 0:
        print('Your favourite number is %d and it is positive.' % (number))
    elif number < 0:
        print('Your favourite number is %d and it is negative.' % (number))
    else:
        print('Your favourite number is %d and it is equal to 0.' % (number))

    subtract()

def subtract():
    salary = float(input('Enter your monthly salary.'))
    expenses = float(input('Enter your monthly expenses'))
    result = (salary - expenses)

    if result < 0:
        print('Save more!')
    else:
        print('Congratulations on saving!')

def final():
    percentage = result / a
    finalpercent = percentage * 100
    
    if finalpercent == 0:
        print('No money!!')
    elif finalpercent < 50:
        print('Getting there...')
    else:
        print('You have lots of money!!')


    


main()
```

What I want is to use the `result` variable from `def subtract():` function in the `def final():` function?

Comment: return the result in subtract method ```return result```. ```result = subtract()``` and pass it to final ```final(result)```.

Answer (score 0):

Make the result variable from the subtract function the return value of that function.

Something like this:

```py
def main():
    name = input('What is your name?')
    age = int(input('What is your age?'))

    number = int(input('What is your favourite number?'))

    if number > 0:
        print('Your favourite number is %d and it is positive.' % (number))
    elif number < 0:
        print('Your favourite number is %d and it is negative.' % (number))
    else:
        print('Your favourite number is %d and it is equal to 0.' % (number))

    final(subtract()) # RESULT IS RETURNED BY SUBTRACT AND THEN USED BY FINAL AS PARAMETER

def subtract():
    salary = float(input('Enter your monthly salary.'))
    expenses = float(input('Enter your monthly expenses'))
    result = (salary - expenses)

    if result < 0:
        print('Save more!')
    else:
        print('Congratulations on saving!')
    
    return result


def final(result):
    percentage = result / a
    finalpercent = percentage * 100
    
    if finalpercent == 0:
        print('No money!!')
    elif finalpercent < 50:
        print('Getting there...')
    else:
        print('You have lots of money!!')


main()
```

Also the variable **a** is not defined in the **final** function, that will cause an error, so check that too :).

Comment: My apologies for any errors. The variable `a` is `salary` from the `def subtract():` How would I also pass the 'salary' variable to the 'final' function?

Comment: Not recommended, but you can use `global result` in the function you declare `result` in. However, it's much better to use a return value and pass that in as a argument.

Comment: @niknik you can return an array in the substract function, something like return [result, salary], update the final function to receive another parameter like def final(result, salary), save the result of calling substract in variable like values = substract() and then call final like final(values[0], values[1])

Comment: @niknik it would probable be better to `return result, salary` within `subtract`. Then in `main`, `result, salary = subtract()` and pass both to `final` like `final(result, salary)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Global` variable. Creating a Global variable means you could access that variable from any function or class.

```
def main():
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    age = int(input('What is your age? '))
    number = int(input('What is your favourite number? '))

    if number > 0:
        print('Your favourite number is %d and it is positive.' % (number))
    elif number < 0:
        print('Your favourite number is %d and it is negative. ' % (number))
    else:
        print('Your favourite number is Zero.')

    subtract()


def subtract():
    global salary                            # Declaring salary as Global Variable
    salary = float(input('Enter your monthly salary: '))
    expenses = float(input('Enter your monthly expenses: '))
    global result                            # Declaring result as Global Variable
    result = (salary - expenses)

    if result < 0:
        print('Save more!')
    else:
        print('Congratulations on saving!')
    
    final()


def final():
    percentage = result / salary
    finalpercent = percentage * 100
    
    if finalpercent == 0:
        print('No money!!')
    elif finalpercent < 50:
        print('Getting there...')
    else:
        print('You have lots of money!!')

main()
```

I convert those local variable salary and result using **global** keyword. so that I could use that two variables outside of that function.

---

Another Approach is to pass that variable as an argument by calling final function. Like this...

```
def main():
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    age = int(input('What is your age? '))
    number = int(input('What is your favourite number? '))

    if number > 0:
        print('Your favourite number is %d and it is positive.' % (number))
    elif number < 0:
        print('Your favourite number is %d and it is negative. ' % (number))
    else:
        print('Your favourite number is Zero.')

    subtract()


def subtract():
    salary = float(input('Enter your monthly salary: '))
    expenses = float(input('Enter your monthly expenses: '))
    result = (salary - expenses)

    if result < 0:
        print('Save more!')
    else:
        print('Congratulations on saving!')
    
    final(result, salary)        # calling final function by passing it as argument


def final(result, salary):
    percentage = result / salary
    finalpercent = percentage * 100
    
    if finalpercent == 0:
        print('No money!!')
    elif finalpercent < 50:
        print('Getting there...')
    else:
        print('You have lots of money!!')

main()
```